# How to block whole sites in the Hot Network Questions list

Tags: feature-request, support, hot-questions

So, *[Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour)* are really getting on my nerves, and I would like to completely block them, so they don't show in hot questions.

Curiosity is not going to allow me to ignore it if I see something interesting, but I also know that it is most likely going to annoy me. So, I would like to blacklist them. How can I do that?